# How do I send a two chained methods as a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, decent-exposure

In order to properly search my Posts using friendly_id, I use this query :

```
Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

But I need to wrap this method up and send it to my presenter class gem, `decent_exposure`. Which gives me a fancy place to include a `method` that would fetch my object.

By default, this method is `:find` . As written in their code :

```
def finder
  options[:finder] || :find
end

scope.send(finder, id) # scope here would mean Post
```

How can I send via options, this two method query as a symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at their documentation quickly if you define a class method on Post you should then be able to use that.

```
class Post
  def self.find_with_friendly(id)
    friendly.find(id)
  end
end
```

Then you can do

```
expose(:post, finder: :find_with_friendly)
```

Pretty sure this should work.

Comment: Ah so simple! Thanks so much friend!

Answer (score 0):

Something like

scope.send(:finder).try(:id) ??